# How do I send an email from gmail within my app?

Tags: php

I have the following code. I would like to send a confirmation email to the user as soon as they click the 'register' button. When I click on the register button my database gets updated with the correct information but it doesn't send the email.

Email.php:

```
<?php
include('class.phpmailer.php');
include('class.smtp.php');
$mail  = new PHPMailer();   
$mail->IsSMTP();

//GMAIL config
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                 // sets the prefix to the server
$mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 465;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = 'xxx@gmail.com';  // GMAIL username
$mail->Password   = 'yyy';            // GMAIL password
//End Gmail

$mail->From       = 'xxx@gmail.com';
$mail->FromName   = 'SYS';
$mail->Subject    = 'Registration Successful';
$mail->MsgHTML('You have successfully been added to the System!');

$mail->AddAddress($_POST['EmailAddress']);
$mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML

if(!$mail->Send()) {//to see if we return a message or a value bolean
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else  echo "Message sent!";

?>
```

This is the part of the code where I get the email address from. I have it so that the user inputs his email address into the textbox. it gets saved as EmailAddress

AddUser.php:

```
<div class="">
<label style=""> Email Address </label>
<input id="Email Address" type="email" name="EmailAddress" value="">                          
</div>
```

My sql query goes here. I include the Email.php file after it.

```
<?php
.
.
.

include('./content/Email.php');
?>
```

This is my button. When the user clicks it, the information gets stored and is supposed to send the email.

```
 </select></div>
 </div>
 </div> 

 <br><br>


 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-submit" value="Add User">

 </div>
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting in your code.

Comment: what happens actually (as opposed to an email being sent).

Comment: Try Swiftmailer (http://swiftmailer.org/)

Comment: Try using `$mail->Body = "You have successfully been added to the System!";` instead of `$mail->MsgHTML()`

Comment: Do you get an error message? Do you get some other output? Have you checked the server's error logs?

Comment: @mnagel it's a form that captures the users information such as email, mobile etc and stores it to my database - that part is working fine. Now what I want is for it to take the email address that the user enters and sends them an email. I'm not getting any errors, the code executes and stores the info to the database without sending the email

Comment: @arbitter I gave that a try. Same result.

Comment: Do you see "Message sent!" after? If not, you're getting some error that's not being reported. To make the errors show up, add the following to the top of your file `error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);` -- remove when you are done debugging!

Comment: The database stuff has nothing to do with your problem, remove it from the example and only focus on email sending.

Comment: @Cixate No errors are being reported. It works like it always has.

Comment: Do you see "Message sent!" after?

Comment: @Cixate No. It's as if the email has been completely ignored

Comment: Then there is an error -- if you don't see "Mailer Error" or "Message sent!" in your output then it's never getting that far because some error occurred. PHP hides errors from the browser unless you change the settings mentioned above. Otherwise, you need to check the server's error logs.